# How customize bxslider?

Tags: jquery, bxslider

i am trying to use bxslider like this http://jsfiddle.net/qLSGe/275/, but i want to custom my slider and look like this[image]

this is my bxslider setup:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.slider1').bxSlider({
    slideWidth: 200,
    minSlides: 2,
    maxSlides: 3,
    slideMargin: 10
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have updated code by changing one css ,try this

```
.bx-wrapper img {
    max-width: 100%;
    display: block;
    padding: 3% !important;
}
```

Working Fiddle :  http://jsfiddle.net/qLSGe/277/